# give margin bottom inside dd class

Tags: html, css, margin

[image: in image two glyphicon that is edit and trash]

i want to give margin bottom to them

code is as shown below,

```
<div class="dd" id="menu_list_drag">
    <?php echo $li; ?>
</div>
```

where `$li` is as shown below,

```
foreach ($p1 as $p) {
        $inner_li = "";
        $p2 = array_filter($menu, function($a)use($p) {
            return $a['parent_id'] == $p['id'];
        });
        if ($p2) {
            $inner_li = $this->generate_li($menu, $p['id']);
        }
        $li .= "<li class='dd-item' data-id='" . $p['id'] .
                "' id='menu-list'><div menu-id='" . $p['id'] . "' id='drag' class='dd-handle'>" . $p['title'] .
                "<div style='float:right; margin-bottom:10px' class='dd-nodrag'>"
                . "<a class='btn-group btn-group-xs edit_menu' data-toggle='tooltip' id='" . $p['id'] .
                "' data-original-title='Edit' onclick='edit_menu($(this))' title='Edit Menu'>"
                . "<i class='btn btn-default edit_area fa fa-pencil'></i></a>"
                . "<a class='btn-group btn-group-xs delete_menu' id='" . $p['id'] .
                "' data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='Delete' delete_type='delete_single' onclick='delete_menu($(this))' title='Deactivate Menu'>"
                . "<i class='btn btn-default fa fa-trash-o'></i></a></div></div>" . $inner_li . "</li>";
    }
    $ol = "<ol class='dd-list'>" . $li . "</ol>";
```

data comes fine but i am unable to give margin bottom to this dd class menu
please help me thank you...

Comment: `.dd {margin-bottom: 10px;}`... sorry, really don't know what more you want... Create working demo, without PHP and tell us what exactly you need.

Comment: Please write your answer and mark it as answered so that others won't think that the question is still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: what i was looking for is this]

i have used this

```
.dd-handle{height:35px;}
```

and it worked for me...!!